# How to expose more than one API in Azure AD B2C App registration?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am wondering, is it possible to expose more than one API in Azure AD B2C App registration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. Each API is represented by an App Registration, so if you have many APIs, each needs an App Reg. the App Reg can expose permissions (scopes) in respect to the API it represents.